# How to look up a value by matching information and create a new variable with same data in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe below.

[image]

I am trying to create a new variable (**oldType**) by matching information , comparing last month's **ID**, **alpha_CLASS**, **num_Class**, and **TYPE**.

[image]

Is it possible to implement this in r?

Your input would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group_by` the columns that contain the same identifying information (i.e., `ID`, `alpha_CLASS`, and `num_Class`), then use `lag` to get the previous month's `TYPE`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID, alpha_CLASS, num_Class) %>% 
  mutate(oldType = lag(TYPE))
```

**Output**

```
   YYYYMM    ID alpha_CLASS num_Class  TYPE oldType
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 202101    11 A           I             9      NA
 2 202101    11 B           II            6      NA
 3 202101    11 C           III           4      NA
 4 202101    11 D           IV            0      NA
 5 202101    11 E           V             8      NA
 6 202101    11 F           VI            7      NA
 7 202102    11 C           III           5       4
 8 202102    11 B           II            6       6
 9 202102    11 F           VI            7       7
10 202102    11 D           IV            0       0
11 202102    11 E           V             8       8
12 202102    11 A           I             9       9
13 202103    11 B           II            6       6
14 202103    11 F           VI            7       7
15 202103    11 A           I             9       9
16 202103    11 C           III           5       5
17 202103    11 E           V             8       8
18 202103    11 D           IV            0       0
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, oldType := shift(.(TYPE), type = "lag"),
   by = c("ID", "alpha_CLASS", "num_Class")]
```

**Data**

```
df < structure(list(YYYYMM = c(202101, 202101, 202101, 202101, 202101, 
202101, 202102, 202102, 202102, 202102, 202102, 202102, 202103, 
202103, 202103, 202103, 202103, 202103), ID = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), alpha_CLASS = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "C", "B", "F", "D", "E", "A", "B", "F", 
"A", "C", "E", "D"), num_Class = c("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", 
"VI", "III", "II", "VI", "IV", "V", "I", "II", "VI", "I", "III", 
"V", "IV"), TYPE = c(9, 6, 4, 0, 8, 7, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 9, 6, 7, 
9, 5, 8, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew! I have one more question. What if I want to compare information only one month prior data? For example, comparing 202103 data to 202102 data, not 202001.

Comment: @IreneJeong I'm not sure I follow you, as each month only gets the prior month. So, instead of doing all the one month prior for each month, you only want to do for one specific month? If so, then we would use an `ifelse` statement so that we aren't calculating all the other prior months.  Like `mutate(oldType = ifelse(YYYYMM == 202103, lag(TYPE), NA))`, then we would only get the prior month for `202103`.